# ipage alter table add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I'm trying to add a foreign key constraint in phpmyadmin through my ipage account.  They don't have the relation view and their syntax for queries makes it really difficult.  I did this successfully a couple months ago but forgot to save the query.

Does anyone know how I can alter the table to add a foreign key constraint?  Here's an example of what I have tried.

```
ALTER TABLE `STRENGTH_T`
ADD FOREIGN KEY (`username`.`STRENGTH_T`)
REFERENCES (`username`.`STUDENT_T`)
```

I've tried several other queries, and like I said, I did do this successfully a couple months ago.  Now I know why my professor always stressed saving your queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE `STRENGTH_T` 
  ADD CONSTRAINT `someName` FOREIGN KEY (`username`) 
  REFERENCES `STUDENT_T` (`username`) ;
```